That The Greatest Common Divisor of Two Numbers is Unique
A book I'm reading on introductory number theory seems to give a quick proof on the uniqueness of the greatest common divisor of two numbers using the greatest-integer principle, namely that "a nonempty set of integers that is bounded above contains a greatest element". However, even though the proof is evanescent, I don't seem to quite understand it:

Note that if $a$ and $b$ are both not zero, then the set of common divisors of $a$ and $b$, is a set of integers that is bounded above by the largest of $a$, $b$, $–a$, $–b$. Hence, by the greatest-integer principle for the integers, the set has a largest element, so the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ exists and is unique.

One thing I don't seme to understand is why the set of common divisors of $a$ and $b$ must include $a$, $b$, $–a$ and $–b$ since it isn't gauanteed that either of these numbers should be a COMMON divisor of both, unless only if $a$ is some multiple of $b$ and vice versa. If someone could please explain this to me, I would be very greatful. Thank you in advance.

Think of is this way perhaps: under no circumstances is the greatest common divisor larger (in magnitude) than the two integers in question.

They $\rm\color{#c00}{bound}$ the magnitude of a gcd $,d,$ like this: $,d\mid a,b\neq 0,\Rightarrow, |d|\le |a|,|b|,\Rightarrow, |d|\le \color{#c00}{{\rm max}(|a|,|b|)}\ \ $

The argument that you quote is not stating that those $4$ numbers are common divisors, just that the largest among them is an upper bound for the set of common divisors. This means that if
$$
M = \max\{a, b, -a, -b\}, 
$$
then for each common divisor $d$ of both $a$ and $b$, we have $d \leq M$.
We just need a bound on the set of common divisors in order to guarantee that the set has a maximum. But there's no suggestion that this maximum is the number $M$.

For a set $X$ of numbers to be bounded above by a number $n$ does not require that $n\in X$, but only that $x\leq n$ for all $x\in X$. The text is hence not claiming that $a,b,-a,-b$ all lie in the set of common divisors, but simply that any common divisor must be smaller than one of these numbers.
